# RouteChangeStart and RouteChangeSuccess event not working on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am listening to routeChangeStart and routeChangeSuccess to show a loader gif while a route is loading.

**ISSUE:**
This is working fine, but when the page loads (location change) we have issues:

1. At times, both events do not fire.
2. Sometimes routeChangeSuccess alone fires.

Confused on how to solve this.

Directive for loader:

```
signup.directive('loader',['$timeout','$rootScope', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><img style="padding:49% 49%" src="/img/loader.gif" alt="loading..."/></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, currentRoute, prevRoute){
                    element.css({'display':'block'});
                    element.next().css({'display':'none'});
                });
                $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, currentRoute, prevRoute){
                    element.css({'display':'none'});
                    element.next().css({'display':'block'});
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    }
}]);
```

In the HTML page, I have:

```
<loader></loader>
<div ng-view="ng-view"></div>
```

And this is my route config:

```
// route config
signup.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'agent_home.html',
            controller: 'agent_homeController',
            resolve : {
                properties: function($rootScope) {
                    // return a $http promise
                    return $rootScope.getProperty();
                }
            }
        })
        .when('/profile/agency', {
            templateUrl: 'edit_agency.html',
            controller: 'edit_agencyController'
        })
        .when('/screen_tenant', {
            templateUrl: 'screen_tenant.html',
            controller: 'screen_tenantController'
        })
        .when('/tenantchat', {
            templateUrl: 'tenant_chat.html',
            controller: 'tanantchatController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: "/home"});
});
```

Comment: do you mean when you reload/refresh page, Only routeChangeSuccess event is firing?

Comment: yes, the issue is when i reload/refresh page. Most of the time only routeChangeSuccess fires and rarely both do not fire

Comment: Yes. when you refresh page, routechangeSuccess Event will get fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the `$timeout` function in the directive and now both the events are working fine:

**Directive (corrected)**

```
signup.directive('loader',['$timeout','$rootScope', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><img src="/img/loader.gif" alt="loading..."/></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, currentRoute, prevRoute){
                element.css({'display':'block'});
                element.next().css({'display':'none'});
            });
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, currentRoute, prevRoute){
                element.css({'display':'none'});
                element.next().css({'display':'block'});
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To Differentiate route change and Page Reload, you can check for previous route.

Case 1. Route Change

```
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, currentRoute, prevRoute){
            //prevRoute!= undefined(You will get value for prevRoute )
               element.css({'display':'none'});
               element.next().css({'display':'block'});
           });
```

Case 1. Page Refresh

```
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, currentRoute, prevRoute){
          //prevRoute === undefined(prevRoute value will be undefined)
               element.css({'display':'none'});
               element.next().css({'display':'block'});
           });
```

Comment: tried that. Although most of time routechangeSuccess fires, it so happens that in some odd cases it does not (as I said)- I kept a simple console.log("test") there and tested.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ved
Found the issue it was the $timeout that I used in the directive- I removed that and now the events are firing correctly. :)